# Why isn't my 11.04 system being upgraded? (because I want to test the latest code for Unity)

Tags: 11.04, unity, updates

I'm currently running Natty, but whenever I do a `sudo apt-get update`, and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, it doesn't update nothing, and this has been happening for a couple of months now. Thanks for any help.

(I can't put my sources.list because askubuntu doesn't let me, due to all the hyperlinks...)

Comment: I just remembered, I'm using 64 bit version of ubuntu.

Comment: Is it installed or running from a live usb?

Comment: it's installed, I upgraded from 10.10 .

Answer (score 2):

I found the [following info](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/apt-setup/+changelog) on Launchpad for Natty, have a read through it and make sure your sources are pointing to the correct repositories.